# One writer, multiple readers in lock-free application

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, atomic

I am  building a program where a variable is modified by only one thread (atomically, full memory barrier in both directions), and read bu multiple threads. Do the reading threads need to read the variable atomically or a simple read is enough ?

Typically (I use gcc but i guess the concept is language independant)

```
int a = 0;
```

In the writing thread :

```
__atomic_add_fetch (&a, 1, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
```

In the reading threads :

```
int b = __atomic_load_n (&a, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);

/ * OR */

int b = a;
```

My guess is that if the only writer puts full barrier in both directions, there should be no race condition but I can't seem to find any confirmation of that...

Thanks !

Comment: A simple read would be a data race which is UB.

Comment: what does UB stand for ?

Comment: That's Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Depending on the code, the compiler could generate code to load `a` into a register once, and never refer to the memory location again--ever. In which case `b` (which is held in a register) would never change.

Comment: That's not really a problem, if I want to prevent that I can mark it volatile. It's more about the loading of the value, not what happens once it's loaded.

Answer (score 1):

To be safe, you should do atomic loads with *seq_cst* or *acquire* memory models. Compiler or CPU can do some tricks to optimize use of cache or registers and don't load the value or load in a different order, so using a load-specific barrier is probably a good idea.

Marking the variable as `volatile` can also help.

Comment: I understand that would be safer, but do I HAVE to do it ? volatile shouldn't be necessary if I don't want an up-to-date value, should it ?

Comment: There's no clear answer. It depends on your particular situation. If you don't need the up-to-date value, atomic load might not be necessary. Unless of course the compiler/CPU optimizes it up the the point that the value is only loaded once and never re-loaded (which is be possible in some border cases).